# Variable amount of dimensions in slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multidimensional array called `resultsten`, with the following shape

```
print np.shape(resultsten)
(3, 3, 6, 10, 1, 9)
```

In some occasions, I use a part of this array in a program called `cleanup`, which then further tears this array apart into `x`, `y`, and `z` arrays:

```
x,y,z = cleanup(resultsten[0,:,:,:,:,:])

def cleanup(resultsmat):
    x = resultsmat[:,:,:,:,2]
    y = resultsmat[:,:,:,:,1]
    z = resultsmat[:,:,:,:,4]
    return x,y,z
```

However, it might also occur that I do not want to put the entire matrix of `resultsten` in my program `cleanup`, thus:

```
x,y,z = cleanup(resultsten[0,0,:,:,:,:])
```

This, of course gives an error, as the indices given to `cleanup` do not match the indices expected.
I was wondering if it is possible to have a variable amount of dimensions included in your slice.

**I would like to know a command that takes all the entries for every dimension, up until the last dimension, where it only takes one index.**

I've seen that is possible to do this for all dimensions except the first, e.g

```
resultsten[1,:,:,:,:,:]
```

gives the same result as:

```
resultsten[1,:]
```

I tried this:

```
resultsten[:,1]
```

but it does not give the required result, Python interprets it like this:

```
resultsten[:,1,:,:,:,:]
```

MWE:

```
def cleanup(resultsmat):
    x = resultsmat[:,:,:,0,2]
    y = resultsmat[:,:,:,0,1]
    z = resultsmat[:,:,:,0,4]
    return x,y,z

resultsten=np.arange(3*3*6*10*1*9).reshape(3,3,6,10,1,9)

x0,y0,z0 = cleanup(resultsten[0,:,:,:,:,:]) #works
x0,y0,z0 = cleanup(resultsten[0,0,:,:,:,:]) #does not work
```

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing

Comment: Not entirely sure, but you may be looking for the Ellipsis object: `resultsmat[...,0,2]` etc. Use the link provided by seberg for more information.

Comment: The Ellipsis is exactly what I'm looking for. I already browsed through the SciPy docs, but I missed the Ellipsis Object. How should I proceed, as I cannot accept comments as answers?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list of slice objects:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(2*3*4*5).reshape(2,3,4,5)


#[:] <-> [slice(None,None, None)]
sliceList = [slice(None, None, None)]*(len(A.shape)-1)
a,b,c,d,e = [A[sliceList+[i]] for i in range(A.shape[-1])]
```

Output:

```
>>> A[:,:,:,0]
array([[[  0,   5,  10,  15],
        [ 20,  25,  30,  35],
        [ 40,  45,  50,  55]],

       [[ 60,  65,  70,  75],
        [ 80,  85,  90,  95],
        [100, 105, 110, 115]]])

>>> a
array([[[  0,   5,  10,  15],
        [ 20,  25,  30,  35],
        [ 40,  45,  50,  55]],

       [[ 60,  65,  70,  75],
        [ 80,  85,  90,  95],
        [100, 105, 110, 115]]])
```

Comment: I found the following helpful -> https://gist.github.com/Kos/4467206. I see Evert posted a better solution in the comments using ellipses `resultsmat[...,0,2]`.